# Auto-layouts are not applying when I change simulator Orientation in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

Hi I am new for `Ios` and I my Main `ViewController` I have added Two `UIView` programmatically using Auto-layouts.

And here my main problem is when I change orientation from portrait to landscape I want to clear constraints and adding them again.

For this I have written the code below, but I do not understand why Auto-layouts are not applying when I change orientation.

Can anyone help me please?

### my code:-

```
 #import "MainViewController.h"


@interface MainViewController (){

    UIView * MainView;
    UIView * SubView;
}

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MainView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    MainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    MainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:MainView];

    [self AppyingAutolayoutsAtPortraint];
}

-(void)AppyingAutolayoutsAtPortraint{

    NSDictionary * HeaderDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(MainView);

    //Appliying Autolayouts for MainView

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[MainView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[MainView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

}

-(void)AppyingAutolayoutsLandAtScpae{

    NSDictionary * HeaderDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(MainView);

    //Appliying Autolayouts for MainView

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[MainView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[MainView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        NSLog(@"portrait");

        [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
        [self AppyingAutolayoutsAtPortraint];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    }

    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeRight");

        [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
        [self AppyingAutolayoutsLandAtScpae];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    }

    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeLeft");

        [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
        [self AppyingAutolayoutsLandAtScpae];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems. When you are applying your autolayout constraints, you are also adding the `MainView` and `SubView`.

I’m not sure why you are adding those subviews at that time.

If you just want to change the constraints, then adding subviews should not be part of that code.

Another possible problem is your use of the visual format language. I've found the VFL to be unreliable in comparison to writing the out the full form for programmatic autolayout constraints.

---

Here are some changes that would help correct these problems.

**Move the following code** from `AppyingAutolayouts`

```
MainView = [[UIView alloc] init];
MainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
MainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:MainView];

SubView = [[UIView alloc] init];
SubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
SubView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:SubView];
```

into `viewDidLoad:`.

**Make the following changes** in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        NSLog(@"portrait");

        [self AppyingAutolayoutsPortrait];
    }

    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeRight");

        [self AppyingAutolayoutsLandscapeRight];
    }

    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"LandscapeLeft");

        [self AppyingAutolayoutsLandscapeLeft];
    }
}
```

> Note that `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is deprecated and you should use `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` instead.

**Make three new methods** for AppyingAutolayoutsPortrait, AppyingAutolayoutsLandscapeRight, AppyingAutolayoutsLandscapeLeft and delete AppyingAutolayouts.

Each method should look like:

```
-(void) AppyingAutolayoutsX {

     [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

     // Add your constraints here.

     [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Comment: i am very new for autolayouts can you update my code please

Comment: Is your layout for iPhone only? If so, size classes are a more straightforward way to handle different layouts for different orientations.

Comment: only i phone and what did i do there is wrong i am not understand if possible please update code Daniel Z

Comment: I wouldn't be able to update your code in a meaningful way as it's not apparent to me what result you are trying to achieve. I suggest you instead use size classes in Interface Builder to create an interface that supports orientation changes automatically.

Comment: my requirement is simple even i change my simulator at any orientation i want to remove and add constraints that's my requirement

Comment: i have updated your code but still constraints are not applying at landscape mode and i have updated my code see above

Comment: where was wrong? i am fully confused state why constraints not applying at land scape mode